# Function returning data to client error

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server (I believe 2008) I am attempting to create a function that splits a string by a delimiter, then checks if the passed in value is equal to the found value from a query. If it is, then the function returns true (as soon as it finds one), otherwise it returns false.

For some reason I get the following error which does not seem to make sense. My reason for thinking that is I feel like there should be a method around this problem. I'm relatively new to SQL Server syntax so any help is appreciated. Here is the error and code it points to...

> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

```
--Inside Function
 SELECT id FROM a_table WHERE name=(SUBSTRING(@configValue, @start, @end - @start))
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        RETURN 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are selecting the id.

You need to just check if it exists.

Example, you dont need to select id, you can select 1... no difference for an exists check.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a_table WHERE name=(SUBSTRING(@configValue, @start, @end - @start)))
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 3):

A loose select returns a resultset and you cannot return that from a function, only from stored procedure.

Rewrite to select the count from that resultset and compare to 0 that way.

```
IF 0<(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a_table WHERE name=(SUBSTRING(@configValue, @start, @end - @start)))
    RETURN 1;
```

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr I was fast in responding, JiggsJedi's query is a tad better, EXISTS returns faster.